# Naming tuples in a column

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a view that references another view in pgsql. This new view will find the max and min date values of a column. I want to print out in a separate column "status" which is the max and which is the min

Code so far, with no attempt at the label:

```
create or replace view Max_Min(status, name, employer, date)
as
SELECT * FROM another_view
WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM another_view)
OR date = (SELECT MIN(date) FROM another_view)
;
```

How can I go about populating the status with "max value" and "min value" strings?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, and is probably faster as well as only a single scan over the table is required:

```
select t.*,
       case 
         when t.date = t.max_date then 'max. date'
         else 'min. date'
       end as status
from (
  select av.*,
         min(av.date) over () as min_date,
         max(av.date) over () as max_date,
  from another_view av
) t
where date in (min_date, max_date)
```

---

Btw: `date` is a horrible name for a column. Not only because it's also a reserved word but more importantly because it doesn't document what the column contains. Is it an "end date", a "start date", a "hire date", a "due date", ...?